# After using gradle-flyway plugin to create test database, how to reference db created in c3p0 config?

Tags: gradle, h2, c3p0, flyway

I was trying to accomplish the following

1) Create h2 database using gradle-flyway plugin before tests run. I was able to create it and place it under ${buildDir}

```
flyway {
    url  = "jdbc:h2:file:${buildDir}/db/test/xxxdb"
    user = 'root'
    locations = [
            'classpath:sql'
    ]
}
```

2) My goal was to write integration tests against this db created in step 1. I am using c3p0 for pooling and here is my configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c3p0-config>
    <default-config>
        <property name="driverClass">org.h2.Driver</property>
        **<property name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:h2:file:@buildDir@/db/test/xxxdb</property>**
        <property name="user">xxx</property>
        <property name="password">xxx</property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">1</property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">50</property>
        <property name="acquireIncrement">1</property>
    </default-config>
</c3p0-config>
```

Questions:

a) How do I configure c3p0 to reference the h2 database present in the build directory created in step 1. c3p0 wants absolute path in `jdbcUrl` property.

b) I configured gradle to replace @buildDir@ with appropriate value using this below gradle task. So the database `jdbcUrl` is configured correctly for c3p0 when I do "gradle build". But when I run the tests though intelliJ, it still reads the `jdbcUrl` with value containing "@buildDir@" as intellij does not run `processTestResources` task before running the test.

```
processTestResources {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [buildDir: buildDir.getAbsolutePath()])
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You should be able to use relative paths. When running from IntelliJ the working directory should be your project directory. From Gradle it will also be the project directory, but in cases of a multi-project build it will be the directory of the current project.

Comment: Mark, Any idea how do I solve this for multi-project build? As you said, intellij is finding relative to the project directory but gradle is finding from the directory of the current project.

Comment: Alternatively you could set the `jdbcUrl` property via a [system property](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#system_properties) which could be configured in the VM options of the IntelliJ [JUnit run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#1).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark for your comments. For relative paths, this is the syntax I had used and now it works with both gradle and intellij.

```
jdbc:h2:file:./db/test/xxxdb
```